# Does "decoration" have to be visual?

Tags: meaning

When I hear the word "decoration" I assume it must be visual. However various definitions don't really require this to be the case (such as "The process or art of decorating or adorning something").

To put it differently, is Li'l Sis correct or incorrect in her usage of the word in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nnzw_i4YmKk)?

Comment: +1 for finding a good English question in the whistler tips video lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoration is not always visual. It can refer to any kind of ornamentation, as in music (appoggiatura, trill, grace notes, etc.), spoken language, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

No.

"Decoration" does not have to be visual, though in most cases it is.

> These two helper functions are decorations for that main function.

Answer (score 2):

Decoration is usually visual, as you always decorate a physical object: decorate a room, decorate a soldier, etc.

In the video, when she says that the whistle is just a decoration, she meant decoration for the car and not for the sound. I would interpret her as "It is just a decoration, just like an alloy wheel is, and so no one should be having a problem with it". I am not sure many would agree with her, though.

Comment: I don't know if she meant it was a visual decoration. You can't really see the whistler unless you look hard in the right places.

Comment: @oadams, What I felt is, she says the whistle is harmless as it is a decoration.